# NSMutableString issue with NSXMLParser

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am having a heck of a time with this -- I am trying to parse an XML file and set the text in a NSMutableString variable in order to later fill in a label's text as you can see below.

In my .h I have the following (simplified);

```
NSMutableString *contentsOfCurrentXMLProperty;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableString *contentsOfCurrentXMLProperty;
```

In my .m:

```
-(void) parseData {
  NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:myData];
  [parser setDelegate:self];
  [parser parse];
  [parser release];
}



 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Title"]) {
    NSLog(@"FOUND TITLE!");
    contentsOfCurrentXMLProperty = [NSMutableString setString:@""];
    }
 }

 -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"TITLE"]) {
       myLabel.text = [contentsOfCurrentXMLProperty stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[br]" withString:@"\n"];
    }
 }

 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
[self.contentsOfCurrentXMLProperty appendString:string];
 }
```

When I run my app, the data is downloaded and parsed correctly. I run into issues when my observer fires off the event again. The parseData method is called and I get an error that I have traced to the line that reads: "contentsOfCurrentXMLProperty = [NSMutableString setString:@""];
"

What is the proper way to create or init a NSMutableString variable for me to use over and over? When/Where is the best place to release it? How do I essentially clear the variable so that when the observer fires off the parseData method it will again be able to set "contentsOfCurrentXMLProperty"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-setString: is an instance method, not a class method. If you already have a valid NSMutableString object assigned to contentsOfCurrentXMLProperty and simply want to clear it, then:

```
contentsOfCurrentXMLProperty = [NSMutableString setString:@""];
```

should be

```
[contentsOfCurrentXMLProperty setString:@""];
```

On the other hand, if you want to assign a new object to contentsOfCurrentXMLProperty, here's one valid way to do it:

```
self.contentsOfCurrentXMLProperty = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:0];
```

Comment: That did the trick. Do I just do [contentsOfCurrentXMLProperty release] in my dealloc?

Comment: Hi, I am running on a similar issue, how do you get the entire content of the xml document and append it to `contentsOfCurrentXMLProperty`, can you share please ? my issue is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702628/get-the-entire-xml-downloaded-data