# Get the entire XML downloaded data

Tags: afnetworking, nsxmlparser

I have an outdated application which use to download an XML document and parse it on the iPhone app, I used the `NSURLConnection` for that purpose:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    //NSLog(@"Response :%@",response);
    responseData = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data 
                                          encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    [responseData appendString:str];
    [str release];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSLog(@"DATA : %@",responseData);   

    if (responseData != nil) {

        [self startParsing:responseData];//Parse the data
        [responseData release];
    }   
}
```

Since moving to use `NSXMLParserDelegate` with `AFXMLRequestOperation`, I cannot figure out a way to get xml data properly:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    [responseData appendString:elementName];
    [responseData appendString:namespaceURI];
    [responseData appendString:qName];

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    [responseData appendString:string];

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    [responseData appendString:elementName];
    [responseData appendString:namespaceURI];
    [responseData appendString:qName];


}
-(void) parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
    [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Downloading completed"];

        NSLog(@"DATA : %@",responseData);//not properly appended, tags delimeters are missing 

        if (responseData != nil) {

            [self startParsing:responseData];
            [responseData release];
        }


}
```

How to append all the data received from the server in the `responseData` mutable string ? I debugged the data received after finishing downloading and the xml is missing tags delimeters `<>`. I think I ma missing the way to get the xml data.

**P.S:** Please note it's important that I get the xml in a `NSMutableString` object.

**@Fermi**

I used `AFURLConnectionOperation` as you recommended, it works fine with my purpose, but I noticed that my received data is not catched by the delegate methods, instead I can get the data in a completion block:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:API_URL]];

AFURLConnectionOperation *operation = [[AFURLConnectionOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.completionBlock = ^{
    NSLog(@"Complete: %@",operation.responseString);//responseString is my data


};
[operation start];
[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Downloading files"];
```

wo since `NSURLConnection` delegate methods are not called, how can I manage failure, etc? Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AFXMLRequestOperation` is explicitly intended to be used to return you an `NSXMLDocument` instance, NOT a raw XML string.

If you want the XML string use `AFURLConnectionOperation` and build the `NSMutableString` the same way you do with `NSURLConnection`.

Comment: Thanx Femi, should I always keep the `NSXMLParserDelegate` methods?

Comment: +1 Ah, I see, `NSURLConnection delegate methods should be implemented`. Thanx, I will try that and get back to you :)

Comment: Hi Fermi, I keep the protocol methods implementation of `NSURLConnection` since they work for `AFURLConnectionOperation` but they are not getting called, please have a look on my edit post. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Looking at http://engineering.gowalla.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFURLConnectionOperation.html#task_Getting%20URL%20Connection%20Information it appears that you have to subclass the AFURLConnectionOperation to implement the delegate callbacks: are you subclassing it? Alternatively you may be able to use the `error` property in the completion block (http://engineering.gowalla.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFURLConnectionOperation.html#//api/name/error).

Comment: @Femi That documentation is extremely out of date. See http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.2.1/ for the latest.

Comment: @mattt thanks for the updated pointer. Looking at http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.2.1/Classes/AFURLConnectionOperation.html#overview, it appears subclassing is still required to use the delegate callbacks.